# nginx set X-Real-IP to downstream proxied servers to prevent spoofing

Tags: nginx

I'm wanting to correctly set X-Real-IP for domains proxied by nginx that also sit behind an amazon ELB.

i.e.

```
AMAZON ELB <=> NGINX PROXY <=> REST APP1
                           <=> REST APP2
```

So far, I've found the following correctly works and prevents spoofing the IP.  I have this set globally in nginx.conf

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

However, I also have some REST apps that sit behind the NGINX

My rest apps will use x-real-ip if set or x-forwarded-for.
Under normal use, the real client IP is correct.

Under a spoofed IP attack where one or both of the x-real-ip and x-forwarded-for headers are set, I see the spoofed IP in the REST client.  However, nginx shows the correct client IP.

Currently in domain host I have set

proxy_pass_request_headers on;

How do set the x-real-ip to be the real trusted IP for the REST apps?

I presume I need a `proxy_set_header` line with X-Real-IP.  But how do I reference what the the real-ip header is set by the real-ip module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I had been trying to set the following directives which I found on the web.  But it didn't seem to work.

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

After some messing around I thought I'd try placing them in a location block. I had tried placing them in the html section and also the server section. However, if you place the above in location block like below it will work. e.g.

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to set those at http/server/location according to the documenttation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header bug perhaps?